# Unable to import a scala object in build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-concat

I have a scala file called `ConcatPlugin.scala` in package `com.mariussoutier.sbt`.

However when I import it in `build.sbt` I get error `cannot resolve symbol ConcatPlugin`

**Build.sbt**

```
import com.mariussoutier.sbt.ConcatPlugin
```

But when I type it in it does show that the class exists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The `ConcatPlugin.scala` file can be found [here](https://github.com/nonameplum/sbt-concat/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mariussoutier/sbt/ConcatPlugin.scala)

Comment: have you tried to compile anyways?

Comment: When I run >activator compile I get this : error: object mariussoutier is not a member
of package com
import com.mariussoutier.sbt.ConcatPlugin

Comment: Is your plugin source file part of the project you want to build? If yes, I don't think this is possible; you have to build your plugin binary separately and reference it in plugins.sbt. More info: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Extending/Plugins.html.

Comment: Yes it's not a part of project. I had to build it separately and I got a jar now called sbt-concat-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar after running sbt package. Where do I place it and how do I reference this in the project ?

Comment: Given that the Scala versions match, it should be sufficient to deploy it to your local maven repository using `sbt publish-local` and to reference it in `plugins.sbt` using organization and artifact ID.

Comment: try `import _root_.com.mariussoutier.sbt.ConcatPlugin`